# When extra bones are added to my rig, why don't they scale correctly?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Normal **scale 1**
[image]

when Enlarged to **scale 1.625**

I have tried using copy scale on the rib bones and its location is going for toss.

[image]

When reduced to **scale 0.647**

[image]

Please help find work around

Comment: Are you scaling in Object mode or Pose mode? Also, the bones you're pointing at appear to have constraints. What constraints do you have on those bones? And one further thing, do you have Inherit Scale disabled for those bones?

Comment: I am scaling in pose mode.
There are "copy location" and "stretch to" constraints
Inherit scale is enabled.

Comment: I have solved it now by adding "spine bone" as parent which is child of root. Hope that's a right solution.